# Nevigate from one page to other page in bootstrape model popup

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, bootstrap-modal

i have grid in which dropdownlist in each row and  the dropdown option itself is clicked on. For all of these, have a bootstrap modal popup.when model pop up i want to fire button click event on model pop up window to navigate on other page.so how to navigate page when i clicked a button from model pop up window.

Comment: i tried java script function and call on Onclick event but its not working so anyone have suggestion for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this in Javascript with

```
Window.Open("URLGOESHERE");
```

Does it need to be a post back event?